# debian squeeze: where do the logs for sysv init scripts go? (why won't my init script work)

Tags: debian, sysv

my actual problem is trying to debug a init script to start Resque. It works fine run as root from the command line, but does nothing on boot. It has some proper insserv headers and I've run `updaterc.d` to create the symlinks, and checked that they exist. The script is +x.

```
# find /etc/rc*.d -name \*resque\*
/etc/rc0.d/K01resque
/etc/rc1.d/K01resque
/etc/rc2.d/S01resque
/etc/rc3.d/S01resque
/etc/rc4.d/S01resque
/etc/rc5.d/S01resque
/etc/rc6.d/K01resque

# ls -l /etc/init.d/resque 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2093 Oct 24 03:02 /etc/init.d/resque
```

the script [can be viewed here](https://raw.github.com/postmodern/resque/247ba05d21a53d7b5b3c86260f3fbe798773ea68/examples/ubuntu/resque) if you like. It uses lsb functions to log messages, which essentially echo() to STDOUT I believe. So where does the output go during startup? It's not in /var/log/*log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of initscripts are not logged anywhere, any output goes to the console. To log the output of the script add this at the top:

```
exec 1>/tmp/init.log 2>&1
```

You may also want to add `set -x` to see exactly how it's being interpreted.

Comment: works great. although resque still isn't coming up on boot at least I know it's not the init script. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Debian Wheezy, do

```
apt-get install bootlogd
```

On previous versions, it is already installed but you need to enable it in `/etc/default/bootlogd`.

The output is then logged to `/var/log/boot`

See https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd for a few more details.